# Angular: Cannot read property 'component' of null

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have a weird issue. I have a basic route configuration like this:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: '/search', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  {path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [OnlyLoggedInGuard]},
  {path: 'search', component: SearchComponent, canActivate: [OnlyLoggedInGuard]}
];
```

On app HTML, I import conditionally the router-outlet:

```
<div *nfIf="condition">
...
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
...
</div>
<div *nfIf="!condition">
... another dom construction
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
...
</div>
```

And I intercept (with an `HttpInterceptor` ) HTTP 401 errors to redirect to login page. Meaning at some point in my http interceptor I have this:

```
this._router.navigate(['/login', {error:'I am an error message'}]);
```

When I'm on the dashboard and a 401 occurs I'm correctly redirected to login page with the correct error parameter.
However, when I'm on the login page and I get a 401 from the server I've got the following error:

```
core.es5.js:1020 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'component' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'component' of null
    at PreActivation.webpackJsonp.../../../router/@angular/router.es5.js.PreActivation.traverseRoutes (router.es5.js:4343)
    at router.es5.js:4305
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at PreActivation.webpackJsonp.../../../router/@angular/router.es5.js.PreActivation.traverseChildRoutes (router.es5.js:4304)
    at PreActivation.webpackJsonp.../../../router/@angular/router.es5.js.PreActivation.traverse (router.es5.js:4261)
    at MapSubscriber.project (router.es5.js:4100)
    at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/map.js.MapSubscriber._next (map.js:77)
    at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (mergeMap.js:143)
    at InnerSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/InnerSubscriber.js.InnerSubscriber._next (InnerSubscriber.js:23)
    at PreActivation.webpackJsonp.../../../router/@angular/router.es5.js.PreActivation.traverseRoutes (router.es5.js:4343)
    at router.es5.js:4305
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at PreActivation.webpackJsonp.../../../router/@angular/router.es5.js.PreActivation.traverseChildRoutes (router.es5.js:4304)
    at PreActivation.webpackJsonp.../../../router/@angular/router.es5.js.PreActivation.traverse (router.es5.js:4261)
    at MapSubscriber.project (router.es5.js:4100)
    at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/map.js.MapSubscriber._next (map.js:77)
    at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (mergeMap.js:143)
    at InnerSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/InnerSubscriber.js.InnerSubscriber._next (InnerSubscriber.js:23)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:783)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:754)
    at zone.js:831
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:424)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:3881)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Zone.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:191)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:595)
    at ZoneTask.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:502)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:1370)
```

Comment: when you open the app then also the server throws 401

Comment: I just receive 401 error when I'm trying to do an action (e.g: login). not when I load the page to begin with.

Comment: Does the error go away if you remove the `canActivate` on the search route?

Comment: No, it doesn't, I already tried removing the guards and only keeping one route from router configuration. I just found a lead to fix this issue. See answer below. Feedback to understand what's going on is welcomed though

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok. I managed to fix this. I do not fully understand but here is what I found:

- The `Cannot read property 'component' of null` disapear when the `router-outlet` is included only once in the app HTML (e.g: contrary to the inclusion of `router-outlet` in each of multiple branches of the `ng-if` condition)
- When I change the conditional inclusion of `router-outlet` from

this form:

```
    <div *nfIf="condition">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
    <div *nfIf="!condition">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
```

to this form:

```
    <div *nfIf="condition;else notcondition">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
    <ng-template #notcondition>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </ng-template>
```

I have no issue navigating from login page to login page with parameters.

Comment: Okay, thought of that, too. I would say this should not be used this way. One case would be, you will have multiple views, so you would have multiple router outlets (you can give them IDs) - but this one is not the case, so I would put one router outlet in a route with subroutes to solve the different views

Comment: The reason I use condition is that I want the DOM surrounding router-outlet to change according to some external factors (application global configuration related things, I don't want the url of my application reflecting these changes). If I get it right, your proposition would imply a change in the URL pattern of my application?

Comment: Yes, this was my intention. If this is "global" like enviroment global - you could conditionally inject the component on bootstrap of the application. Otherwise this maybe could be achieved wrapping a component conditionally or with CSS

Comment: Should this be reported as an Angular bug?

Comment: I suspect that this is a bug in angular and it seems like this PR might address it: https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/19374

Comment: I got the same error, but this workaround doesn't work for me. I don't have multiple router-outlet. Actually, I don't have any canActivate guard (but only canDeactivate guard), so I don't understand why it's complaining about PreActivation.

Comment: okay, I found the workaround for me...just don't use router.navigate, but use window.location.href instead.

Comment: You could create a component that uses ng-content to switch out the DOM surrounding the router-outlet: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r1pvca

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the DOM surrounding the router-outlet you could create a component that handles that and uses ng-content to place the router-outlet:

```
<!-- layout.component.html -->
<div *ngIf="condition" style="background: yellow">
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="ngContent"></ng-container>
</div>

<div *ngIf="!condition" style="background: green">
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="ngContent"></ng-container>
</div>

<ng-template #ngContent>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</ng-template>
```

Then use it in app.component.html like this:

```
<app-layout [condition]="condition">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</app-layout>
```

I still had to do something with `*ngIf` though, as it started complaining when I added 2 of them in `layout.component.html`. I don't know if this is something you are looking for, but here's the stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r1pvca.